# Getting error in passing in a GZip stream

Tags: c#

I am getting 'The magic number in GZip header is not correct. Make sure you are passing in a GZip stream' error when i m executing this code:

```
using (Stream requestStream = ((WebRequest)httpWebRequest).GetRequestStream())
{
    using (StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(requestStream))
       streamWriter.Write(requestString);
}
using (HttpWebResponse httpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse) httpWebRequest.GetResponse())
{
    using (GZipStream gzipStream = new GZipStream(httpWebResponse.GetResponseStream(), CompressionMode.Decompress))
       str = new StreamReader((Stream) gzipStream).ReadToEnd();
}
```

Comment: is the server actually returning gzip data?

Comment: yes, sometimes that error is coming after 'using (GZipStream gzipStream = new GZipStream(httpWebResponse.GetResponseStream(), CompressionMode.Decompress))' line

Answer (score 0):

You can use built-in `AutomaticDecompression` property of `HttpWebRequest`. Just add the following line after creating request, and use default `GetResponseStream`:

```
request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;
```